# Laravel displaying / logging errors

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

So I've just spent quite some time on something that should have been very quick to fix.

I'm on a local environment, with debug set to true. I was working on a php file which implements the `Jsonable` interface, and I got the compatibility a bit wrong. Unfortunatly, when I ran this file, it simply showed a 500 error and a completely blank, white page, without any errors.

I checked my error log, and that didn't have any errors in it (relating to this issue) either.

I found online that setting `debug` to `true` in Laravel hides sets `display_errors` to `0`. I quickly did a `ini_set('display_errors', 1)` in my called controller and I got the `fatal error` message I was looking for!

**My question is:**

How can I display these fatal errors etc (not exceptions) in Laravel when `debug` is true, without specifying `ini_set('display_errors', 1)` in all my controllers?! Why does Laravel hide errors when in debug mode anyway?! It's very frustrating having an error which isn't displayed (even when in debug mode), and isn't logged!

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not a laravel user, but... maybe it's sending these messages into a log file instead? It might also be a problem with some custom code you added - e.g. you forgot to return a response inside a controller

Comment: @PhilCross Laravel uses the [Symfony Debug Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/debug/index.html) to handle error, which is the one disabling `display_errors`. Before registering it's custom handler (@RyanVincent your suggestion of using `set_error_handler` is already implemented by the Larave's [`HandleExceptions`](http://bit.ly/1PI0pxp) class) the defaults are the ones that come from the `php.ini`, so it might be just that you have `display_errors` set to `0` by default the error might occur before Laravel might have a chance to register its handler.

Comment: So the easy fix for this would be to enable `display_errors` by default for your PHP installation. My general recommendation is to use a debugger such a [Xdebug](https://xdebug.org/) as it's way more efficient to track down problems within your code. Either way, I'm curious what was the exception and scenario that lead to this problem.

Comment: @RyanVincent Also [implemented](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php#L37) in the same class mentioned above. There's really no need to try and modify error handling in Laravel.

Comment: @RyanVincent I've explained the possible cause in this case in my previous comment: the custom error handler is registered after some things such as the application instance and service container are fired up; if an exception is thrown before the custom handler is registered, all error reporting is done according to the defaults for the PHP installation, and if `display_errors` is off in `php.ini` then you get a blank page.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I admit this is the first time I've experience this problem with Laravel, so I'm not sure whether I've just not come across this behaviour before, or whether I've accidently done something to alter logging behaviour! @Bogdan the problem arose from creating a custom exception class which implemented `Jsonable` interface, but I missed out the `$options = 0` parameter by accident, which resulted in a `fatal error`. Thanks for your replies :)